# What does the alias after DELETE mean?

Tags: delete

What does the alias after DELETE mean?

E.g. I have a query:

```
DELETE p1
FROM Person p1, Person p2
WHERE p1.Email = p2.Email AND p2.Id < p1.Id
```

What does it mean `DELETE p1`?

I understand it as follows. First we find a cartesian product of the `Person` table with itself. Then we remove all the rows where the `Email` from the both tables (`p1` and `p2`) is not the same. Then we remove all the rows where the `Id` from the `p2` is greater or equal than the `Id` from `p1`. Now we are left with some rows. We pick all the `Id`s from the `p1` part of the left rows and remove all the entries from the initial `Person` table, which has the `Id` contained in the picked `Id`s.

Is my understanding correct?

If it is correct, then `DELETE p1` means delete all entries in `Person` where `Id` is in the resulting `p1` part of the rows.

Comment: You may want to tag your DBMS as this syntax is not universally supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that the deletion is a process which consists from 2 steps. At the 1st step the server performs according `SELECT *` selection, and marks the rows which must be deleted. At the 2nd step it deletes marked rows.

DELETE **p1** in your query means that only rows selected from a table aliased as `p1` must be marked for deletion. If you'd use DELETE **p1, p2** or simply DELETE FROM then selected rows from all table copies 'd be marked.